# Minify Sencha Touch 2 Application code?

Tags: cordova, extjs, phonegap-build

I have built a Phonegap android Sencha Touch 2 application. How can i minify Sencha code? Do i need to use Sencha sdk tool? How can i get the app with all js files minified?

Answer (score 0):

sencha sdk tools are old, don`t use them. for sencha touch 2.x you can use sencha cmd. that tool allows to minifier your sencha touch app with custom js like phonegap stuff (also custom css is supported). to minifier you have to run the production build command. after that step you can build your native app.